# Basic Authentication Issues

Tags: java, basic-authentication

I have these variables:

```
private String name = "name";
private String password = "password";

private String authString = name + ":" + password;
private byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
private String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
```

And in my Java program I have the below code:

```
HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field authStringEnc
```

If I then change my variables to static I get the below error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setRequestProperty(String, String) from the type URLConnection
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The name and password?
I made all static:
    private static String name = "name";
    private static String password = "password";

    private static String authString = name + ":" + password;
    private static byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
    private static String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

Comment: Apologies for the dupe. Think it's resolved now with :

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);